# check in remote host a services with monit

Tags: service, monit

Good, I have a monit machine which monitors me several hosts, but I also need that from those hosts I verify several services that run on the remote hosts and not on the local machine, I can not find the syntax to do it, I do not know if it is possible to do it. I have what I have until now.

```
CHECK HOST L10 ADDRESS X.X.X.X
    if failed icmp type echo count 3 with timeout 35 seconds then alert
    if failed port XX protocol smtp with timeout 35 seconds then alert
    if failed port XX with timeout 35 seconds for 2 cycles then alert
    if failed port XX protocol ssh with timeout 35 seconds for 2 cycles then alert
```

In the remote host shown above, I need to verify that the pmta service is running, run under /usr/sbin/pmtad or it would also work for me like this: (I know that the syntax shown below for monit is not valid because it gave me an error, but for you to understand what I want to do)

```
pmtad=$(service pmta status)

if [ $pmtad !=0 ] then alert
```

Thank you very much in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

Except through native network check or via external custom scrip usage, Monit is not able to perform action on a remote host. Monit is only running locally and therefore can only check or act locally.

It is not possible with native check without custom scripts.